# Swift 2でsplit関数の使い方がわからない。

Tags: swift

`split()`でエラーが出てしまいます。環境はXcode 7 bata5です。bata4では以下のソースで問題ありません。

エラーコード

```
split(_:maxSplit:allowEmptySlices:isSeparator:)' is unavailable: Use the split() method instead.
```

```
import Cocoa
import Foundation
import RealmSwift
extension String : CollectionType {}

class ViewController: NSViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    let filePath = paths[0].stringByAppendingString("/test01.txt")
    print (filePath)
    let data = htmlStringWithFilePath(filePath)

    data!.enumerateLines { (line, stop) -> () in
        print(line)
        print(split(line){ $0 == "\t"})
    }

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

改善策わかる方、教えていただければ幸いです。

Comment: 仕様変更のようです。print(line.split("\t"))に置き換えで、いけました。お騒がせいたしました。